# Change responsive slider height with scale transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to make the rslides style transition with scale transition like the way clients div is changing after the clients link is clicked, here is the fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/vladicorp/ktqfq/1/**

**HTML CODE:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="sections">
    <div id="slider">
        <div id="index_slider">
                 <ul class="rslides" >
                             <li><img src="http://www.emocool.com/work/slide2.jpg"></li>
                             <li><img src="http://www.emocool.com/work/slide2.jpg"></li>                      
                 </ul></div></div>
<script src="http://www.emocool.com/work/js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
    speed: 1000,
    maxwidth: 1200
      });
  });
</script>

<div id="menu"><a href="#sections">clients</a>  </div>

<div id="clients">gfgd</div>
<div id="services"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="contacts"></div>
        </div></div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background:#fff;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px)  {
#container {
    width:1200px;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:40;
    position:relative;

}}
@media (max-width: 1200px)  {
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:40;
    position:relative;
}}

.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
  transition:all 1s ease;   


}

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }

#index_slider
{
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;  


}
#slider {
margin: 0 auto;


}

a {
    color:#fff;

}

/* menu styles */ 

#menu {
    background:#181818;
    color:#6e7166;
    height:63px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;

}

/* sections */ 

    #sections {
        transition:all 1s ease; 
    }

    #clients {
        height:44px;
        background:#333;
        position:relative;
        float:left;

    }


    #sections:target #clients {
        height:90px;
        background:#333;
        transition:all 1s ease;
    }

    #sections:target .rslides {
        height:0px;
        transition:all 1s ease;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

adding the height of the slides fixed it:

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
  transition:all 1s ease;
  height:432px;



}
```